ImageMagick: shaded colors become total black
I need to convert a pdf file containing only one image to a .jpeg or .png format using ImageMagick.
This is the image. Original PDF file: https://file.io/WMEsCGtbodwz

Using the command line
convert -density 150 output.pdf -quality 100 -flatten -sharpen 0x1.0 output.jpg

The three-dimensional curve becomes totally black.


Post the actual PDF file. Zip it first to be sure it does not get changed. Upload to some free hosting service and put the URL here.    Try convert -density 150 output.pdf -alpha off -background white -sharpen 0x1.0 -quality 100 output.jpg

As far as I'm aware ImageMagick still uses Ghostscript to render PDF files to an image format (there is a delegate entry in the config file you could check but I don't recall it offhand). You should check what version of Ghostscript you have installed. You could also use Ghostscript to render the file to a lossless image format (such as TIFF) impot that into IM and do whaever else you want there.

@fmw42 https://file.io/WMEsCGtbodwz

Your PDF file has an alpha channel. That may be messing up your result. So do the following in Imagemagick 6.9.13-11 and Ghostscript 10.03.0 installed (mandatory to read PDFs). This is supersampling technique that is better than trying to sharpen your output. So you should use a large density, then resize by the inverse amount.  Normal density is 72, so I have done 4x enlarging via -density 288, then I resize by 1/4=25%.  If you want a larger output, resize by a larger percent and/or use a larger density.
So far PNG output:
convert -density 288 output.pdf -alpha off -resize 25% output.png


and for JPG
convert -density 288 output.pdf -alpha off -resize 25% output.jpg


If this does not work, be sure you have Ghostscript installed.  Then show what you get from convert -version and what your platform is.

P.S. I know k/mol should be kcal/mol. It's a siunitx LaTeX package issue.
